# How to use SQL to determine number of JSON objects in a parent object

Tags: json, sql-server

I have the following JSON example (done as an image to make it clearer)

[image]

EDIT: I've been asked to include some of the JSON:

```
[
   {
      "ServiceUserDetails":[
         {
            "ServiceUserName":"Resident 1",
            "ServiceUserDateOfBirth":"08/03/37",
            "ServiceUserID":"ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82ebb",
            "TotalFluidDrunk":47120,
            "TotalFluidOffered":48920,
            "DayDetails":[
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1950,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1950,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-02T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1500,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1500,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-03T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1450,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1600,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-04T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1350,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1350,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-05T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1630,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1750,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-06T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1950,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":2100,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-07T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1640,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1640,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-08T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1550,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1550,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-09T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1270,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1310,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-10T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1845,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1880,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-11T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1200,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1200,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-12T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1100,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1200,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-13T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1240,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1350,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-14T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1000,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1000,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-15T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1335,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1350,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-16T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1670,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1670,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-17T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1680,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1700,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-18T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1600,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1600,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-19T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1500,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1500,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-20T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1850,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1980,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-21T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1990,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1990,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-22T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1600,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1600,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-23T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1585,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1750,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-24T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1465,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1640,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-25T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1595,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1600,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-26T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1555,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1650,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-27T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1560,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1710,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-28T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1550,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1550,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-29T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1350,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1450,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-30T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1400,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1500,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-12-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1160,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1300,
                  "LineDetails":null
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
```

I am trying to work out how many DayDetails objects are present for each person referenced in the ServiceUserDetails object. The aim of this code is to extract fluid levels for a period (typically a month), based on them being offered or drinking 1000ml per day, so the TotalFluidDrunk / Offered, divided by the number of days. I would just do 30 days, so 30000ml, but sometimes it will be 28, sometimes 29 and other times 31 and I want to be precise. Also, some people may have been on the system for less than a complete time period, so this would also skew them into showing as having less fluid than they should.

I have my standard code now I've used elsewhere that CROSS APPLY references through the objects to get to what I need, ie:

```
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, ''$.ServiceUserDetails'') 
        WITH
        (
            ServiceUserName nvarchar(75) ''$.ServiceUserName'',
            ServiceUserDateOfBirth nvarchar(10) ''$.ServiceUserDateOfBirth'',
            ServiceUserID nvarchar(100) ''$.ServiceUserID'',
            TotalFluidDrunk nvarchar(7) ''$.TotalFluidDrunk'',
            TotalFluidOffered nvarchar(7) ''$.TotalFluidOffered'',
            DayDetails nvarchar(max) ''$.DayDetails'' as JSON   
        ) j1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J1.DayDetails)
        WITH
        (
            Date nvarchar(10) ''$.Date'',
            DailyFluidDrunk nvarchar(7) ''$.DailyFluidDrunk'',
            DailyFluidOffered nvarchar(7) ''$.DailyFluidOffered'',
            LineDetails nvarchar(255) ''$.LineDetails''
        ) j2
```

But I don't know how to produce this number at THIS stage. So I thought I'd produce a further JSON extract again (not efficient, I know):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, N''$.ServiceUserDetails'')
WITH (DayDetails nvarchar(max) ''$.DayDetails'' as JSON) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.DayDetails ) WITH
(DailyFluidDrunk nvarchar(6) ''$.DailyFluidDrunk'') j2
```

But of course, I just seem to get a number of ALL the DayDetails throughout the JSON string.

Help!

Cheers
Ant

Comment: Can you post the example JSON as text? Thanks.

Comment: *"done as an image to make it clearer"* But it does not make in consumable; in fact it makes it useless to us as now we have no sample data.

Comment: Added, but thought this way it would've been easier. Noted for future. Attached.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
[{"ServiceUserDetails":

[
{"ServiceUserName":"Resident 1","ServiceUserDateOfBirth":"08/03/37","ServiceUserID":"a1fa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82ebb","TotalFluidDrunk":47120,"TotalFluidOffered":48920,
"DayDetails":[
    {"Date":"2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1950,"DailyFluidOffered":1950,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-02T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1500,"DailyFluidOffered":1500,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-03T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1450,"DailyFluidOffered":1600,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-04T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1350,"DailyFluidOffered":1350,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-05T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1630,"DailyFluidOffered":1750,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-06T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1950,"DailyFluidOffered":2100,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-07T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1640,"DailyFluidOffered":1640,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-08T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1550,"DailyFluidOffered":1550,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-09T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1270,"DailyFluidOffered":1310,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-10T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1845,"DailyFluidOffered":1880,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-11T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1200,"DailyFluidOffered":1200,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-12T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1100,"DailyFluidOffered":1200,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-13T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1240,"DailyFluidOffered":1350,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-14T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1000,"DailyFluidOffered":1000,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-15T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1335,"DailyFluidOffered":1350,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-16T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1670,"DailyFluidOffered":1670,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-17T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1680,"DailyFluidOffered":1700,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-18T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1600,"DailyFluidOffered":1600,"LineDetails":null}
    ]},
{"ServiceUserName":"Resident 2","ServiceUserDateOfBirth":"08/03/37","ServiceUserID":"b2fa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82ebb","TotalFluidDrunk":47120,"TotalFluidOffered":48920,
"DayDetails":[
    {"Date":"2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":50,"DailyFluidOffered":1950,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-02T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":15,"DailyFluidOffered":1500,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-03T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":100,"DailyFluidOffered":1600,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-04T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":130,"DailyFluidOffered":1350,"LineDetails":null}
    ]},
{"ServiceUserName":"Resident 3","ServiceUserDateOfBirth":"08/03/37","ServiceUserID":"c3fa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82ebb","TotalFluidDrunk":47120,"TotalFluidOffered":48920,
"DayDetails":[
    {"Date":"2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1950,"DailyFluidOffered":1950,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-02T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1500,"DailyFluidOffered":1500,"LineDetails":null},
    {"Date":"2019-11-03T00:00:00+00:00","DailyFluidDrunk":1450,"DailyFluidOffered":1600,"LineDetails":null}
    ]
}
]

}]
';

SELECT 
    u.ServiceUserName, u.ServiceUserID, 
    agr.NumberOfDays, agr.SumDailyFluidDrunk, agr.SumDailyFluidOffered
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$')
WITH 
(
    sud  NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.ServiceUserDetails' AS JSON 
) AS s
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(s.sud)
WITH
(
    ServiceUserName NVARCHAR(10) '$.ServiceUserName',
    ServiceUserID nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUserID',
    DayDetails nvarchar(max) '$.DayDetails' AS JSON   
) AS u
CROSS APPLY --aggregation of day details
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDays, SUM(DailyFluidDrunk) AS SumDailyFluidDrunk, SUM(DailyFluidOffered) AS SumDailyFluidOffered
    FROM OPENJSON(u.DayDetails)
    WITH
    (
        Date DATE ,
        DailyFluidDrunk INT,
        DailyFluidOffered INT,
        LineDetails NVARCHAR(100)
    ) AS dd
    WHERE 1=1
    --AND s.Date >= @FromDate
    --AND s.Date < @ToDate
    --AND......
) AS agr
```

Answer (score 0):

The next example may help you to find a solution to your problem. When you use `OPENJSON()` with default schema, the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of JSON array, the `key` column holds the index of each item in this array.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
   {
      "ServiceUserDetails":[
         {
            "ServiceUserName":"Resident 1",
            "ServiceUserDateOfBirth":"08/03/37",
            "ServiceUserID":"ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82ebb",
            "TotalFluidDrunk":47120,
            "TotalFluidOffered":48920,
            "DayDetails":[
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1950,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1950,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-02T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1500,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1500,
                  "LineDetails":null
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "ServiceUserName":"Resident 2",
            "ServiceUserDateOfBirth":"08/03/37",
            "ServiceUserID":"ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82ebb",
            "TotalFluidDrunk":47120,
            "TotalFluidOffered":48920,
            "DayDetails":[
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1950,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1950,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1950,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1950,
                  "LineDetails":null
               },
               {
                  "Date":"2019-11-02T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "DailyFluidDrunk":1500,
                  "DailyFluidOffered":1500,
                  "LineDetails":null
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j1.ServiceUserName, j2.DayDetailsCount
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.ServiceUserDetails') WITH (
   ServiceUserName nvarchar(75) '$.ServiceUserName',
   DayDetails nvarchar(max) '$.DayDetails' as JSON 
) j1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT MAX(CONVERT(int, [key])) + 1 AS DayDetailsCount 
   FROM OPENJSON(j1.DayDetails)
) j2
```

Result:

```
------------------------------- 
ServiceUserName DayDetailsCount
------------------------------- 
Resident 1      2
Resident 2      3
```

Note, that `COUNT()` also returns the expected results:

```
SELECT j1.ServiceUserName, j2.DayDetailsCount
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.ServiceUserDetails') WITH (
   ServiceUserName nvarchar(75) '$.ServiceUserName',
   DayDetails nvarchar(max) '$.DayDetails' as JSON 
) j1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS DayDetailsCount 
   FROM OPENJSON(j1.DayDetails)
) j2
```

Comment: Hi @zhorov. This does work, and picks up people who don't have a full set. But they all seem to stop at 10. I can't particularly see why it would do this?

Comment: @Ant You are right, `key` is `nvarchar(4000)`, so you need a `CONVERT`. The answer is updated. Thanks, my mistake.

Comment: I'll let you off, lol. Thanks so much @zhorov. This now works a dream. One further question though, please can you explain why it needed converting?

Comment: @Ant Because when you order numbers, represented as text, the order is different. If you have numbers (as character data type) from `0` to `14`, `MAX(...)` will return `9`, while for numbers from `1` to `14` (as numeric data type) `MAX(CONVERT(int, ...))` will return `14`. This explains `10` as max value.

Comment: @Ant Approach with `COUNT` is also an option, see updated answer.